# XmlDocument.LoadXML Name cannot begin with the '<' character

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I get the error "Name cannot begin with the '<' character" when i try to pass a value including html tag like `<table>, <div> ...` to display items into xslt file using XsltArgumentList to pass these values into xslt file and use XslCompiledTransform to pass all content of xslt file with passed values. Finally using LoadXml to load but the error will occur and i try to use "< to replace < and > to replace >" but error still occur. Could anyone give me some suggestion to solve it ?

my code :

```
var objXslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

        objXslt.Load(EmailTemplate);
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateElement("EmailMessage"));
        var xpathNav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();

        var xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
        if (objDictionary != null)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in objDictionary)
            {
                xslArg.AddParam(entry.Key.ToString(), "", entry.Value);
            }
        }

        var emailBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(emailBuilder)) {Formatting = Formatting.Indented};
        objXslt.Transform(xpathNav, xslArg, xmlWriter);

        var emailDoc = new XmlDocument();

        emailDoc.LoadXml(emailBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: Please show a small example of the XML that causes this problem.

Comment: thanks john, i found where the problem is. Problem caused by i missed the close tag of img element in string value which i used to pass to a parem in my xslt file

Comment: FYI, don't use "new XmlTextWriter()". Use "XmlWriter.Create()"

Answer (score 0):

I Have found a solution to fix. I write stringbuilder into a html file and check. Finally, the problem lay in the missing of close tag of img element in string value which i use to pass into xslt file as a parameter.